# H2OFrame - How to replace NA values in selected columns

Tags: r, h2o

I was wandering about this and finally found an answer I would like to share here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2ostream/M9rIi0k6K08

If you have an H2OFrame like this:

```
  a   b    c    d    e
1 0   NA   NA   NA   NA
2 0   2    2    2    2
3 0   NA   NA   NA   NA
4 0   NA   NA   1    2
5 0   NA   NA   NA   NA
6 0   1    2    3    2
```

And would like to replace all NAs in column b with 0s to gain this:

```
  a   b    c    d    e
1 0   0    NA   NA   NA
2 0   2    2    2    2
3 0   0    NA   NA   NA
4 0   0    NA   1    2
5 0   0    NA   NA   NA
6 0   1    2    3    2
```

Comment: The referenced question is about R native data.frames and data.tables. This Q&A explicitly handles H2OFrames which are indexed differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then this code will do it:

```
h2o_frame[is.na(h2o_frame$b), "b"] <- 0
```

All the credits to Spencer Aiello on the H2O Google forum!

Comment: This solution will work on a base R `data.frame` too, so not sure what's your problem with the linked dupe.